# resuming server replication on PostgreSQL servers

Tags: postgresql, replication, archive-log

I got one main server and other two servers are replicating from the main.

I got full disk space on the main server (I have an `archive_command` that put wal archives into the `/wal_archive/` directory).

It got full, and the PostgreSQL log shows the error:

```
archive command failed:

    2019-06-04 09:52:49.079 EEST [3365] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
    2019-06-04 09:52:49.079 EEST [3365] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: test ! -f /wal_archive/000000010000028C0000003B && cp pg_xlog/000000010000028C0000003B /wal_archive/000000010000028C0000003B
```

I cleaned up the `/wal_archive/` directory with `pg_archivecleanup`, but PostgreSQL still throws the same error.

I have tried to reload PostgreSQL config without making changes to the config itself and without restart using:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql reload
```

but still the same, in log, PostgreSQL throws an error.
How should I resume wal_archive copying to the wal_archive directory?

Should I change `archive_command` to `true`, reload, and change archive back to original again?

I'm trying to avoid restarting the server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like archiving managed to partly write the WAL archive file before the space ran out.

Then the `test` in your `archive_command` will notice that there is already a fike of that name and will fail.

In this case the solution would be to manually remove that partially archived WAL segment so that the next attempt to archive it can succeed.

You might want to improve your `archive_command` by removing the file if `cp` fails (while still returning a non-zero return code).

Comment: Thank you. It worked! But the question is, that "not full" file (wal_archive) will be created full, or it will be a hole in wal_archives files?

Comment: Update: yes, removed wal_archive file was reacreated. No missing wal_archives.

Comment: The original WAL file is still in `pg_wal`. It was not successfully archived the first time. If you remove the obstacle, PostgreSQL will archive the file again, so no part will be missing.